# Max value from multiple ActiveRecord relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a group of 5 AR objects each from a different model however each has a common field being likes_count

I would like to identify the AR object with the greatest value in likes_count

```
a = Student.where("likes_count > 0").order_by("likes_count DESC").first
b = Teacher.where("likes_count > 0").order_by("likes_count DESC").first
c = Class.where("likes_count > 0").order_by("likes_count DESC").first
d = School.where("likes_count > 0").order_by("likes_count DESC").first
```

I could achieve this with a if statements however this will be very messy. Is there an easier way ?

It is theoretically possible that each object will be nil.

Comment: How about Raw SQL using UNION and MAX query?

Comment: I need to the original AR object returned each each is from a different model.

Comment: You need to specify what DB you are using.

Comment: You can't name a Rails model `Class`, so I am assuming this is example code. Is STI involved at all, or are these all separate tables?

Comment: Yes, simplified example code. Separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to combine this into a single Rails model by using a [View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html).

```
CREATE VIEW top_likes AS
  SELECT 'Student' as likeable_type, id as likeable_id, likes_count 
  FROM students
  ORDER BY likes_count DESC
  LIMIT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Teacher' as likeable_type, id as likeable_id, likes_count 
  FROM teachers
  ORDER BY likes_count DESC
  LIMIT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Class' as likeable_type, id as likeable_id, likes_count
  FROM classes
  ORDER BY likes_count DESC
  LIMIT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'School' as likeable_type, id as likeable_id, likes_count
  FROM schools
  ORDER BY likes_count DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

You can point a model to a view just like it's a table.

```
class TopLikes < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'top_likes'

  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end

TopLikes.order(likes_count: :desc).first
```

Another approach to this is by creating a [Query Object](https://medium.flatstack.com/query-object-in-ruby-on-rails-56ea434365f0) that encapsulates this SQL and returns the correct model.